# shopify speed page fully hack?

Tags: performance, shopify, pagespeed-insights

```
<script type="text/javascript"> const observer = new MutationObserver(e => { e.forEach(({ addedNodes: e }) => { e.forEach(e => { 1 === e.nodeType && "SCRIPT" === e.tagName && (e.innerHTML.includes("asyncLoad") && (e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace("if(window.attachEvent)", "document.addEventListener('asyncLazyLoad',function(event){asyncLoad();});if(window.attachEvent)").replaceAll(", asyncLoad", ", function(){}")), e.innerHTML.includes("PreviewBarInjector") && (e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace("DOMContentLoaded", "asyncLazyLoad")), (e.className == 'analytics') && (e.type = 'text/lazyload'),(e.src.includes("assets/storefront/features")||e.src.includes("assets/shopify_pay")||e.src.includes("connect.facebook.net"))&&(e.setAttribute("data-src", e.src), e.removeAttribute("src")))})})});observer.observe(document.documentElement,{childList:!0,subtree:!0})</script>{{ "//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0603/7530/2276/t/1/assets/optimizers.js" | script_tag}}
```

i did try this script use in theme.liquid file in head tag ,after content*for*header tag..but this is not a helpful for our store..how use this code in shopify store??